# Why does Earth-833 look like this?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home, design

In *Spider-Man: Far From Home*,

> Mysterio (Quentin Beck) explains that he's from Earth-833, while the main setting of the MCU is Earth-616.

Now, of course,

> It turned out to have been a fabrication.

But that planet is still holographically depicted and it appears to have

> large swathes of the continents (in particular South America and Australia) either missing or underwater.

From a story-telling perspective, it needed to appear noticeably different to the audience.   But why did the creators of that hologram design it that way (in their justification)?  It is because:

> - The planet is just different than ours?
> - It was caused by the Elementals?
> - That world had rampart climate change leading to higher sea levels?

Answer (score 7):

Beck explained that he was too late to save "his Earth" from the Elementals and that they eventually destroyed it. If I remember correctly the hologram eventually shows this with the Molten-Man having destroying the planet engulfing it in flame. Before that though the Hydro-Man would have attacked and presumably flooded large portions of the Earth. Sandman would also have destroyed areas of the world as well which might have even led to landmasses breaking apart. As Beck is trying to persuade them that this happened it makes sense to show the effects that the Elementals had with their attacks. For this particular case it then makes sense to show that portions of the Earth were flooded and other land masses were broken up.

I can't find the exact quote I'm looking for or a still of the hologram but the below one hints at how much devastation they left. It also shows that all the Elementals survived to have made it to "this Earth" and so Hydro-Man and Sandman would have had a deep impact on "Beck's Earth".

> **Quentin Beck:** They first materialized on my Earth many years ago. I was part of the last battalion left trying to stop them. All we did was delay the inevitable.
>
> **"Maria Hill":** The Elementals are here now.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: Far From Home*</sub>

Comment: I agree, that is a likely explanation, but it is more than a supposition?

Comment: @ThePopMachine It is mainly supposition but the most likely reason in my opinion. I've found a quote that I believe backs up my theory somewhat but I think there is a better one from the same scene I just can't find yet.